# Run length encoding

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, runtime

What is the best we can do with run length encoding.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) suggests the time complexity is O(m*n) where m is the number of time the number repeats..

Is the a more efficient algorithm to do RLE?

Answer (score 3):

I think you maybe mis-understood the runtime. The algorithm on the wikipedia page is O(n) (where n is the length of the input). Notice how the index is the same for both loops, and increasing.

Comment: Note that this is the best you can do (compression algorithms typically require reading over the data, thus minimum O(n))

Answer (score 0):

As already stated the time complexity is O(n). More efficient algorithms use SIMD or CUDA to process more than one element at a time.

You might have a look at an efficient and fast implementation: [TurboRLE:Run Length Encoding](https://github.com/powturbo/Turbo-Run-Length-Encoding) including SIMD. A benchmark program is also provided.